# Can't find Trash in Finder or on Desktop

Tags: macos, trash

I can't find the trashcan icon anywhere.

I'm using OS X 10.7.4. I'm not sure when it went missing.

I can still move items to the trash, but since I can't find it I can't empty it.

Is there a way to get the icons back, or an absolute path to it?

Note: I'm not using Time Machine.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your Dock.

Comment: @duci9y Oops, there it is. I found it.

Comment: … And you can also empty your trash by choosing `Finder` → `Empty trash…` from the menu bar (when Finder is active, that is).

Comment: this question would benefit from an answer that describes how to find Trash in the finder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It’s on the right corner of your Dock.

Comment: haha, damn auto-hiding dock